# Set theory - Inclusion map vs identity map

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around inclusion maps and identity maps...

if X is a subset of Y, the function f defined by f(x)=x for each x in X is called the inclusion map of X into Y.

If X={1,2,3} and Y={1,2,3,4,5}. Then f={(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}?

The inclusion map of X into X is called identity map on X. (In the language of relations, the identity map on X is the same as the relation of equality in X)

So in my example the inclusion map = identity map. Can someone give me an example of where this is not true?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: So, $X\ne X{}{}$?

Comment: You mean like the inclusion map of one set into another set that properly contains it?

Comment: You denote two distinct sets both by $X$. That is confusing.

Comment: drhab it's the way it's written in the book :)

Comment: What book is this from, Paul?

Comment: @Paul That is no excuse, right? In cases like that be better than your book. That can give you a nice feeling ;-).

Comment: Naive set theory - kindle edition

Comment: Thanks. I have a copy of it - which page or section does he use $X$ to stand for two sets at the same time? I'm curious to see it in print.

Comment: Halmos explains the relationship in an entire paragraph, at the bottom of page 30 in section 8, via the concept of the restriction of a function to a smaller domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion map $A\to B$ is always the same *set of pairs* as the identity map on $A$.

So if you're in a context where maps are simply sets of pairs (and, in particular, a map has a range but does not have a unique codomain), then they are the same.

On the other hand, at least informally (and in quite a number of formal contexts too) it is usual and convenient to speak of a map as "knowing" what its domain and codomain are. In that case the inclusion map $A\to B$ differs from the identity map, because (assuming $B$ is a *proper* superset of $A$) their codomains are different -- even though both have the same domain and they have the same value at every point in the domain.

This perspective is needed, for example, if we want to ask whether the map is *surjective* or not. The identity map is a surjection; a nontrivial inclusion map is not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please give me an example of the different codomains?

Comment: @Paul: $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ would seem to be an excellent example.

Comment: Hmm I'm still confused as to how the codomains are different. I guess I need to do some more study, I'm new to this...

Comment: @Paul: They're _defined_ to be different. The identity map _by definition_ has domain $A$ and codomain $A$; the injection map by definition has domain $A$ and codomain $B$.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help...still confused though

Comment: So where Halmos write X into Y or X into X. He is writing domain into codomain?

Comment: @Paul: In Halmos' conventions the function itself does not have a codomain, but he always says something like "$f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$" to let you know the codomain $Y$ that he is interested in. Similarly, he will say "$f$ maps $X$ onto $Y$" to let you know that $Y$ is the range of $f$.  This is because, in set theory, it is usually not very important what the codomain of a function is. In other areas, such as analysis, the issue is more important, and so they often take the codomain to be part of the function itself rather than part of the way we talk about the function.

Answer (score 0):

A map is not defined only by a set of arrows $x\mapsto f(x)$, it is defined by a domain and a codomain.

The maps $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R:x\mapsto |x|$ and $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R_+:x\mapsto |x|$ are two different maps.

If $A\subset B$,

- the inclusion map is defined as $A\to B : x\mapsto x$,
- the identity map is defined as $A\to A : x\mapsto x$.

The output is the same, but the codomain isn't.

Comment: This is a common convention, but Halmos uses a slightly different convention, in which those two are the same map.  Instead of saying something like "$f$ is surjective", he always says "$f$ maps $X$ onto $Y$", viewing surjectivity as a property of $f$ and $Y$ together rather than as a property of $f$ alone.  Similarly, in Halmos' conventions, a map from $X$ to $Y$ is also a map from $X$ to $Z$ whenever $Y \subseteq Z$.